# Devise gem - authenticate_user! issues - Not able to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm getting this error on successful login username and password

```
You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
```

otherwise I get

```
Invalid email or password.
```

If I remove index action from authentication!, login is happening properly but no other links(actions) are working. They intern redirecting me to sign in page.

This issue started after upgrading my ruby version from **1.9.3 to 2.1.3.**

OS - Mac Yosemite(10.10.1)

Can someone please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your sessions working? Can you check it with `irb`?

Comment: Yeah, I can connect to db from console if that's what you were asking

Comment: I think you have added :confirmable in your model file and you have't confirm your account.

Comment: Nope. My model looks like below

Comment: devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable